# Resource files error in c++

Tags: winapi, resources, winapp

I need some help with resource files. I don't understand the mistake I've made in this files.

> resource.h line 5 error: unqualified-id before numeric constants, resources.rc line 6 note: in
>   expansion of macro 'IDI_MYICON'

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include "resource.h"

const char g_szClassName[] = "myWindowsClass";

//Windows procedure

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        {
            HMENU hMenu, hSubMenu;
            HICON hIcon, hIconSm;

            hMenu = CreateMenu();

            hSubMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
            AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_STRING, ID_FILE_EXIT,"E&xit");
            AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP, (UINT)hSubMenu,"&File");

            hSubMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
            AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_STRING, ID_STUFF_GO, "&Go");

            SetMenu(hwnd, hMenu);

            hIcon = (HICON)LoadImage(NULL, "menu_two.ico", IMAGE_ICON, 32, 32, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
            if(hIcon)
                SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG, (LPARAM)hIcon);
            else
                MessageBox(hwnd, "Could not load large icon!", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
            hIconSm = (HICON)LoadImage(NULL, "menu_two.ico", IMAGE_ICON, 16, 16, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
            if(hIconSm)
                SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETICON, ICON_SMALL, (LPARAM)hIconSm);
            else
                MessageBox(hwnd, "Could not load small icon!", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        }
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch(LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case ID_FILE_EXIT:
            PostMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0,0);
            break;
        case ID_STUFF_GO:

            break;
        }
        break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{

    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG Msg;

    //Registering the Window class
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_WAIT);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Registration Failed!", "Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    //Ceating the window
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, g_szClassName, "Shopping program", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 544, 375, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if(hwnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Creation Failed!", "Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    //The Message Loop
    while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }

    return Msg.wParam;
}
```

**resource.h:**

```
#include "resources.rc"

#define ID_FILE_EXIT 4001
#define ID_STUFF_GO 9002
#define IDI_MYICON 9008
```

**resources.rc:**

```
#ifndef _RESOURCES_RC_
#define _RESOURCES_RC_

#include "resource.h"

IDI_MYICON ICON "menu_two.ico"

IDR_MYMENU MENU
{
    POPUP "&File"
    {
        MENUITEM "E&xit", ID_FILE_EXIT
    }
}
#endif //_RESOURCES_RC_
```

Answer (score 1):

The `resource.h` file should not #include the `resources.rc` file.